# I cannot install Django in my Virtual Environment

Tags: python, django, pip, virtualenv, pipenv

I wanted to install Django in my virtual environment (which was completely working), but got this whole lot of errors. Anyone know what to do?

I just typed this in PowerShell:

```
 pipenv install django
```

And got this:

```
Error:  An error occurred while installing django!
Error text: Collecting django
  Using cached Django-3.1.7-py3-none-any.whl (7.8 MB)

ERROR: THESE PACKAGES DO NOT MATCH THE HASHES FROM Pipfile.lock!. If you have updated the package versions, please update the hashes. Otherwise, examine the package contents carefully; someone may have tampered with them.
    django from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b8/6f/9a4415cc4fe9228e26ea53cf2005961799b2abb8da0411e519fdb74754fa/Django-3.1.7-py3-none-any.whl#sha256=baf099db36ad31f970775d0be5587cc58a6256a6771a44eb795b554d45f211b8 (from -r c:\users\vojtěch\appdata\local\temp\pipenv-e9otm_0m-requirements\pipenv-sj4h6g3_-requirement.txt (line 1)):
        Expected sha256 baf099db36ad31f970775d0be5587cc58a6256a6771a44eb795b554d45f211b8
             Got        764ad5e659cd3a7740b314806b39c67501c6136a21d23652515df3bfb4023d76
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your original download may have failed, and pip is using the cached download instead of getting a new one. Try `pipenv lock --clear` and then `pipenv install django` again.